# cannot find module '@angular/http'?

Tags: angular

I added the following property to my `systemjs.config.js` map object in my Angular 2 app:

```
'@angular/http': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/http'
```

When I ctrl-click on the url it attempts to download a js file. However, when I try to import from '`@angular/http`' at the top of my service.ts, the compiler returns the error "`Cannot find module '@angular/http`'.`"

Is there an additional step that I'm missing in order for this module to be recognized and usable by my angular app? I'm using Angular version 2.0.0-rc.4.

Comment: Can you share your systemjs.config.js?

Comment: I put systemjs.config.js in this plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mGCDGuYmyzv1ykJl7HtY?p=catalogue

Comment: There are no errors. Even I don't see any service.ts

Answer (score 124):

run this in terminal:

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

**Update for Angular 5+ versions:**

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
```

instead of HttpModule and Http respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much very nice.

Comment: `http` was deprecated in Angular 5 and then removed. For Angular >= 4.3, `HttpClient` must be used (see @DevGaud's answer below)

Comment: very helpful ! thanks

Answer (score 31):

The entire @angular/http package has been removed. Use @angular/common/http.
so instead of importing this one

```
'@angular/http'
```

use this

```
'@angular/common/http'
```

for further information about other changes go to [Angular- Deprecated APIs and Features](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp)

Comment: It worked, but also I had to change `import { Http }` to `import { HttpClient }` in Angular 8. Final syntax : `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'`

Comment: Yeah, they also updated the 'Http' class to 'HttpClient'. Now I think about it, my answer could have more upvotes. Anyway thanks for giving the final syntax, people might find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I used: import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
since I wanted to use it in NgModule({ imports})

Comment: npm install @angular/common@latest, Use this command

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried adding

```
"@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
```

to your package.json file?
Once you do run npm install and you should be golden.

Answer (score 8):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

instead of

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

And in app.module.ts :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to have latest version of http. Try the following command in terminal, hope this will solve your problem...

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

Answer (score 7):

1.This worked for me.Try installing latest angular http

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

2.Also you can try use

```
'@angular/common/http'
```

instead of this

```
'@angular/http'
```

The reason for the second option is

The following APIs have been removed starting with **version 8.0.0**:

*PACKAGE    API REPLACEMENT NOTES*

```
@angular/http
```

All exports replaced with

```
@angular/common/http
```

Answer (score 5):

I use below command & **"cannot find module '@angular/http'"** issue get solved.

**npm install @angular/http@latest**

Answer (score 3):

Just node command prompt, go to project folder and run

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

If there is any severity found as sometimes it show after you install, just use

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 3):

use this command for instaling http modules
**npm install @angular/http@latest**

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install by running below command

```
npm i @angular/http
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire `@angular/http` package has been **removed**. Use `@angular/common/http` instead.

**Replace** `HttpModule` with `HttpClientModule` (from @angular/common/http) in each of your modules.

So you can import like:
`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

for more info, read this: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp

Answer (score 2):

@angular/http is deprecated.

Try:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

refer to https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp for more info.

If you insist on using @angular/http try:

```
npm install @angular/http@latest

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 2):

@angular/http is deprecated

try this:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
```

in the constructor:

```
 constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works! HttpClientModule

```
*import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';*

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    *HttpClientModule,*
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[It worked in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7owSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

CDN path is - https://npmcdn.com/@angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4/

By default, `systemjs.config.js` looks for `index.js` in this path.

Refer this plunker example - https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Also, make sure while importing use below syntax-

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I tried including the cdn path you provided for the http ref I included in my config file.  I tried it with and without the trailing slash but I still got the same errors. I did a file compare between my config file and the one you provided on your plunk but the only diffs were that http was removed from your map and the routerVer minor version was different.

Comment: Here's a plunk with a full working version of a service that angular.io provides online:

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/server-communication/ts/plnkr.html

My config.js is the same as the one provided in the example plunk. Therefore, my build failure [Cannot find module '@angular/http'] does not appear to be due to gaps in my config file. I even copied/pasted the import from the example into my service.ts to account for possible typos or other weirdness. I checked the output console of the build and no additional info was returned. Any ideas for additional troubleshooting?

Comment: can you please share your complete example in plunker? so that we can look any typo or any other mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @angular/http@2.1.2
```

version 2.1.2 is required